# I can't login in my android app when download it from PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

I have an android app that has a login and OTP features.
I have generated the release version of the app and we were able to use it when we download it from external link.
However, when we download the same app from PlayStore, we are unable to pass the OTP Screen although we receive the otp.
Whenever we add the otp number, it just remain in the same page and we can't proceed.

My point is, why we have different behavior when we download the app from the PlayStore?
What can we do to debug or troubleshoot the app in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any difference between the app that you submitted to the play console and the release app you generated if it is the same android package.

If you really want to check, you could use the testing track to test your app.
More information here https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/test-tracks

Comment: yes we are using it in the test-track. and there was no issues with the first and second releases.. only the third one which we uploaded today has the issue.

Comment: then you might check for the backend API response to your app. Does it have an invalid response, or unexpected response that your app doesn't handled yet?

Comment: no it doesn't have any errors with the api responses. and as i mentioned when we can use the app with no issues if we are not downloading it from the store.

Comment: Strange. I'd never experienced that kind of issues. AFAIK there won't be any differences between the app that you submitted and the launch on play store itself as long as the same android package is used. And if you implemented the test tracks, you're downloading it from the store. It's just the access rights that differs.